# Clojure finger trees and flexvec

Tags: clojure, finger-tree

I am looking for a persistent sequential datastructure that allows efficient random insertions and deletions. I found the following implementations:

- [clojure.data.finger-tree](https://github.com/clojure/data.finger-tree) (the counted-double-list implementation)
- [wgjo.data.cljs](https://github.com/wagjo/data.cljs)
- [flexvec](https://github.com/michalmarczyk/flexvec)

Since there was not much activity in clojure.data.finger-tree for the last two years, and the others are relatively new, I was wondering if someone has experince of using any of these in production, and whether there are alternatives that I have overlooked.

Comment: Why is clojure's PersistentVector not good enough? Can you add details on your use case?

Comment: @ordnungswidrig, in response to your request for my use case: I have a document that is represented as an array. In response to events, the document is updated with inserts and deletes at a particular offset within the document. Usually there will be only one or two inserts or deletes in a relatively large document. With clojure's persistent vector implementation I have to re-create the document on each event. With a finger-tree, for example, I would be able to split and join the document along the modified offsets.

Comment: Because of structual shareing this should not impose a big cost. Or do you need access to the split parts, e.g. for optimized on disk persistence?

Comment: @ordnungswidrig if you re-create the vector that represents the document, there will be no structural sharing of that vector. The problem is, you can't insert or delete elements inside a vector with constant time operations.

Answer (score 1):

Another implementation [clojure/core.rrb-vector](https://github.com/clojure/core.rrb-vector) was [announced](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/clojure/Z7wtm2Lepj0). Since it's in the clojure github account, it seems like it's going to be the de-facto implementation.

Comment: clojure/core.rrb-vector is just Michal's flexvec moved over to be a contrib library.